# Turn Current Date in Custom Field Ouput Green or Red

Tags: custom-field

Using a custom field of "Due" how would I change the current date to green or red depending on if it has expired or not? Could someone point me in the right direction? My meta key is simply "Due"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the text/background colour is easy [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp). You can do this with javascript or easier just add a style to the `<div>` with a PHP condintion

```
<?php
if ( $due == true )
    echo '<div style="color: red">';
else
    echo '<div style="color: black">';
?>
```

Comment: Thanks mate, but I do not see the if part of the statement, only the <div style="color: black"> is being output :(

Comment: @Jagst3r15 How about you edit your question to show the code you want to change. Show the HTML container and how you set the '$due'

Answer (score 0):

```
$due = get_post_meta($post->ID,'Due',true);
$class = (strtotime('today') <= $due) ? 'current' : 'expired';
echo '<div class="'.$class.'">content</div>';
```

Create your CSS rules to style those however you want.

The big "if" is going to be with how you've stored the dates in the database. That code assumes that you've stored Unix timestamps.